# How to Insert data in to Related List on Contact Object

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, related-list

Below is the apex class which i have written to insert data in to related list    on contact.i am not getting error while executing the class but the data in not getting saved in the related list object.kindly let me know where i am doing wrong?

```
public class IntralinksExtension {

    public IntralinksExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    }
    Public Contact Cont{get;set;}
    public String ContactId {get;set;}
    public string IntragroupId {get;set;}


    Public void Save(){
        ContactId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
        IntragroupId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('ILPG1');

        List<Contact> Cnt = New List<Contact>([select Id,Name,(select Id,Name from Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__r)from Contact where Id=:ContactId]);
        if(!Cnt.isEmpty()){
            Cnt[0].Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__r[0].Contact__c = ContactId;
           Cnt[0].Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__r[0].Intralinks_Portal_Group__c = IntragroupId;
            insert Cnt; 
        }
    }
```

Below is the Visualforce Page code

```
     <apex:page Standardcontroller="Contact"   extensions="IntralinksExtension" recordSetVar="Intralinks Groups">
       <apex:form >
         <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="window.close()"/>
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>

<apex:pageBlockSection Title="New Intralinks Portal Group" Columns="1" >

 <apex:inputField label="Contact" value="{!Cont.ContactLookup__c}"/>
 <apex:param name="ContactId" value="{!Cont.ContactLookup__c}"/>

  <apex:inputField label="IntraLinks Portal Group" value="          
    {!Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c}"/>
    <apex:param name="IntragroupId" value="

      {!Cont.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c}"/>

   </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>
      </apex:page>
```

Comment: can you post your vf page code as well? it seems like you are not getting Id from page.

Comment: I have added my VF page code

Comment: you are not passing Id from the page and it is coming from url please make sure your are passing Id instead of id. notice the lowercase

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in your object model, `Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links` is a junction object for a many-to-many relationship between `Contact` and `Intralinks_Portal_Group__c`.

The issue with your logic is that you're querying the *existing* junction objects, resetting their contact Id (which is already set) and the `Intralinks_Portal_Group__c` and then inserting it (which should fail because the record already exists).

If I understand your intention, what you need to do is create a new `Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links` record, like this:

```
Public void Save(){
    ContactId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
    IntragroupId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('ILPG1');

    Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__c junction = new Intralinks_Group_and_Contact_Links__c ();
    junction.Contact__c = ContactId;
    junction.Intralinks_Portal_Group__c = IntragroupId;
    insert junction;
}
```

I would also create unit test coverage to ensure that your code is working correctly.

Comment: I did the changes which you have mentioned now when i am entering values on vf page and click on save i am getting below error.    System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Contact, Intralinks Portal Group]: [Contact, Intralinks Portal Group]
Error is in expression '{!Save}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page addintralinksgrouppage: Class.IntralinksExtension.Save: line 18, column 1

Comment: You know the object model better than we do. What are the required fields on that object? What have you done to try and fix the error? Have you created unit tests to test your controller before testing it via the VF page?

Comment: Required Fields are Contact__c and Intralinks_Portal_Group__c

Comment: i have written a unit test to enter some sample records in junction object.but the records are not getting saved in the object.are there any other things like sharing settings or security settings which i need to consider?

Comment: Well, we are setting `Contact__c` and `Intralinks_Portal_Group__c`, aren't we? I think that probably the values you read from `getParameters()` are wrong. Instead of reading them from parameters, I would use VF data binding to bind it to the two properties you have (`ContactId` and `IntragroupId`) directly. Also, your unit tests will not save records... any records created by the unit tests will be deleted. Your tests should assert that the records are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why no contacts are being inserted might be due to the fact that your execution does not pass though this if statement  `if(!Cnt.isEmpty())`. So I would suggest adding some `System.debug()` statements to check if the contactId is a valid one and if your list has any values in it.